# Objective-C: Xcode Prefix Header (.pch file) redundant #import

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import, include, pch

Can't I leave out #import "foo.h" in .m file if it's already in the prefix header?

The product still builds successfully when I leave it out. But, I've noticed that the Xcode templates keep them in. Why?

Is the answer the same for #include?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do Xcode templates have #imports that duplicate Prefix.pch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462288/why-do-xcode-templates-have-imports-that-duplicate-prefix-pch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it does this, but it doesn't hurt because `#import` protects from double `#include` by checking if something is already `#import`-ed or `#include`-d, so no, the same scenario wouldn't work with #include.